# Iterating through a Vec within a struct - cannot move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust

I am writing a function for a struct which contains a `Vec` where I attempt to iterate through the `Vec`:

```
struct Object {
    pub v: Vec<f32>,
}

impl Object {
    pub fn sum(&self) -> f32 {
        let mut sum = 0.0;
        for e in self.v {
            sum += e;
        }
        sum
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         for e in self.v {
  |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

My understanding is that since `self` is borrowed and that the for loop iteration is attempting to move the elements of `v` out into `e`.

From the error code, I read that a potential solution is to take ownership but I'm not quite certain how to do that.

I'm not trying to modify the vector or its elements. I just want to use the elements to run some computation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The line: `for e in self.v` is essentially saying `for e in (*self).v`; you're attempting to iterate over the vector by move, invoking its [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait. This would destroy the vector completely, moving all the numbers out of it forever, which is not only not what you want, but also not allowed in this context because you're only allowed to read it.

You actually want to iterate over it by reference. There are two ways to do this:

```
for e in &self.v {
    // ...
}
```

This is essentially saying `&((*self).v)`, since the `.` auto-dereferences you need to tell the compiler that you actually just want to borrow the vector.

or

```
for e in self.v.iter() {
    // ...
}
```

This may look funny because `iter` takes an `&self`. Why? Well, the compiler also auto-references if you call a function on a value that takes a reference. This is essentially `(&((*self).v)).iter()`, but that would suck to write so the compiler helps out.

So why doesn't it auto-reference in the `for` loop? Well, `for x in self.v` is a valid statement, and that may be what you intended to write. It's usually more important for the compiler to tell you that what you want want is impossible than assume you wanted something else. With the auto (de-)referencing above, no such ambiguity exists.

The former solution is preferred, but the latter is necessary if you want to use an iterator adapter.

Speaking of which, your `sum` already exists: just write `self.v.iter().sum()`.

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly. Thanks so much. So does this mean that whenever the call `self.struct_member` the rust compiler views it as `(*self).struct_member` and move out of the struct? Or is that particular to the `for x in self.v` construct

Comment: @illeyezur That's what always happens (except for `Copy` types, but that's because `Copy` types don't move in general).